# Semantic Form Dropdown get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I am using a Semantic Dropdown in one of my forms. I am adding the options using jinja2 as shown below.

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="set">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Class</div>
    <div class="menu">
        {% for set in sets %}
        <div class="item"  data-value="{{ set.id }}">{{ set.name }}</div>

        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the `data-value` with javascript, and this is what I am currently using:

```
var setID = $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('get value');
```

However when I use `console.log(setID)` nothing is printed.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: I had an if statement further down with 1 `=` instead of two so it overwrote setID's value.